# Plot only certain points in R

Tags: r, plot

There is a very dense set of points I need to show - the pdf gets very large and I was thinking about only plotting every 10th data point

Example

```
plot(c(1:100),runif(100))
```

How do I only plot every 4th data? I know I could create a new input data frame but isn't there some easier thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237557/extracting-every-nth-element-of-a-vector might help you.

Comment: Also see http://www.r-bloggers.com/fix-overplotting-with-colored-contour-lines/ for some ideas to help with overplotting. `smoothScatter` is the base R solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
x <- runif(100)

# Every 10th element
plot(x[seq.int(1, length(x), 10)])

# Every 4th element
plot(x[seq.int(1, length(x), 4)])
```