# How get the element from the vector which is in even positions (2, 4, 6, 8, etc) IN R

Tags: r

Anyone can help me how to construct the R code. I want to get the element from the vector which is in even position.

[image]

The image contains the whole list and i need to pick the elements which is in even position (2,4,6,8,etc).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237557/extracting-every-nth-element-of-a-vector

Comment: Another almost-dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/r-how-to-list-every-other-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
winners[seq(2, length(winners), by = 2)]
```

Or use `%%`

```
winners[seq_along(winners) %%2 == 0]
```

Comment: Once again I strongly advise against obscure implicit conversions, i.e. instead of `!foo %% 2` I would write `foo %% 2 == 0`. But this approach is in fact the solution I’d use, as I find it the most logical.

Comment: No codegolf allowed when Konrad's around

Comment: @DavidArenburg Only on codegolf.stackexchange.com ;-) Maybe I need to change my name to “Konrad Nogolph”.

Comment: Now why the heck was this downvoted?!

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I guess it was for the posting the time earlier.

Comment: @akrun Possible, though by the time that was edited out, your post was still at +1.

Answer (score 6):

Two observations can be combined to solve this:

1. Logical indices allow you to pick an element based on a condition:

   ```
   c(1, 2)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
   ```

   picks the first element but not the second.
2. Indices that are shorter than your array are *recycled* until the end of the array:

   ```
   letters[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   letters[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, …)]
   ```

   and picks, `'a'`, `'c'`, `'e'`, etc.

So you can just use:

```
winner[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colon operator for this:

```
winner[2*(1:(length(winner)/2))]
```