# Apply a function to every nth element in vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector in R:

```
> v <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50)
```

I would like to apply a function to every nth element of the vector and have it return the new vector. For example, let's say I would like to multiply every third element of the vector by 2. I would then get

```
> v
[1] 5 10 30 20 25 60 35 40 90 50
```

I have managed to extract elements using vector logic:

```
> v[c(rep(FALSE,2),TRUE)]
[1] 15 30 45
```

meaning I have figured out how to access the elements and I am able to do things to them, but I don't know how to get them back into my original vector `v`.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237557/extracting-every-nth-element-of-a-vector

Answer (score 8):

We need to assign

```
v[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)] <- v[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]*2
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution using `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(1:length(v) %% 3 == 0, v * 2, v)
# [1]  5 10 30 20 25 60 35 40 90 50
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to use `seq`. You specify `n` at will, and `seq` will start a sequence at `n`, by `n` until the end of your vector (`length(v)`).

```
n <- 3
v[seq(n, length(v), n)] <- v[seq(n, length(v), n)]*2

> v
 [1]  5 10 30 20 25 60 35 40 90 50
```

Answer (score 3):

Using tidyverse:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    p <- seq(v) %% 3 == 0
    f <- function(x) x*2
    map_if(v, p, f) %>% as_vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop:

```
i=0  
while (i < (length(v)-1) ){
    i=i+3
    v[i]=v[i]*2
}

> v
 [1]  5 10 30 20 25 60 35 40 90 50
```

Comment: A bit overkill to use loops on a vector, with this logic we can add forloop, apply family functions solutions, too.