# How do I create a vector with an increment step?

Tags: r, sequence

How do I generate a vector with a specified increment step (e.g. 2)? For example, how do I produce the following

```
1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
```

I want to do it with the function 1:19 with the jump of 2.

I know the `seq` function, I want to know if there is a way to create the vector in this way `1:19(with jumps of 2)` ?

Comment: Check `?seq`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i know the seq function.
i want to know if there is a way to create the vector in this way 1:19(with jumps of 2)

Comment: 2*(1:10)-1 or 2*(0:9)+1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Since yo know the `seq` function, you should know that it contains a `by` argument, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "extract every nth" https://stackoverflow.com/q/5237557/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `logical vector` (length 2 but which will be recycled) to subset `1:19`:

```
(1:19)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
# [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Answer (score 3):

Use seq (type `?seq` into the R console for details):

```
vec = seq(1, 19, 2)
```

where `from = 1, to = 19, by = 2`.

Comment: `seq` is the most natural and direct way to generate an incremental vector.